# ¿Cómo implementar un buscador en una lista desplegable?

Tags: javascript, html, modal, crud

Quisiera implementar en mi `CRUD` un buscador dentro de mi lista desplegable como muestro en la imagen adjunta, más abajo dejo mi código del desplegable que estoy trabajando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="row">  
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nivel"><strong>NIVEL</strong></label>
            <select type="" name="nivel" id="nivel" class="form-control" >   
                <option value="0"><strong></strong></option>
                <option value="INICIAL"><strong>INICIAL</strong></option>
                <option value="PRIMARIA"><strong>PRIMARIA</strong></option>
                <option value="SECUNDARIA"><strong>SECUNDARIA</strong></option>
                <option value="EBA"><strong>EBA</strong></option>
                <option value="EBE"><strong>EBE</strong></option>
                <option value="CETPRO"><strong>CETPRO</strong></option>                         
                <option value="UGEL"><strong>UGEL</strong></option>
                <option value="OTRO"><strong>OTRO</strong></option>
            </select>                 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes pegar la parte de javascript que lleves hecha?

Comment: Podrías echarle un ojo a la herramienta Select2: https://select2.org/

Comment: Aun no tengo nada en Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

como estás?

Te recomendaría en este caso utilizar el siguiente plugin de jquery:

https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Con ese vas a poder implementar todo tipo de selects con búsqueda, filtros y multiselect.
Vas a tener que usar javascript y jquery para ello.

Comment: Gracias, por la respuesta. Probaré.